# Is it possible to detect from where data was copied to my USB?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Someone had copied someone's private data onto my USB.
Is it possible to detect from where or which system copied data to my USB?

Comment: USBs don't track that info. Individual files might track what device created it. This is tracked by Office documents, for instance. But the device that created/edited the file might not be the one that copied the file to your drive.

Comment: @schroeder is there anyway I can find out which device created those file?

Comment: I answered that above